# Load page into div before ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a website on which I load subpages into container div through jquery.load().

On one subpage after user fill in form and submits it. I use ajax to process this form. It is a long process (php search big database) and until I get success I cannot move to another supage because when i click other navigation button it stills on load() functions and waits until this ajax is finished. I dont want to freeze navigation because of this ajax did not finished. So load() cannot be executed until ajax finish? How to do that?

Comment: You could put the form in an iframe and just submit it normally, without ajax.  Since you're talking about navigating away from the page before you get a response I don't see the point in using ajax.  What happens if there are errors in the form?

Answer (score 0):

I would change my .load()'s into [jQuery.get()'s](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Then, I'd cancel my ajax call when the user clicks another nav button. [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery). jQuery.get() returns a XHR (or equivelant) object just like $.ajax does.